# Keeping my window open in Tkinter application after voice recognition and synthesis

Tags: python, tkinter

I was experimenting with a simple Personal Assistant app that listens to user input and provides answers based upon the input.  The original file came from a tutorial that simply had the program listen for prompts and respond in a never ending loop.

I added a simple window and a button to call the function to start the process.  It works once and then the application quits.  I want the application window to remain open and allow the user to press the button again to give further input.

Here is the main.py file:

```
from assistant_functions.weather import get_weather

# speech synthesis
import pyttsx3

import pyaudio

import speech_recognition as sr

from tkinter import *

from intent_classification.intent_classification import IntentClassifier
intent_classifier = IntentClassifier()

# create the window
root = Tk()
root.title("Pythia Personal Assistant")


def on_click():
    assistant.main()


# create a button
my_button = Button(root, text="Click Me", padx=30, pady=20, command=on_click)


my_button.pack()


class Assistant:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # Create instance variable name

        # Code for text-to-speech engine
        self.speech_engine = pyttsx3.init()
        self.speech_engine.setProperty("rate", 150)  # Speed of the voice

        self.r = sr.Recognizer()  # Speech recognizer
        self.mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)  # Change device_index

    def main(self):
        # While True:
        said = self.listen()
        self.reply(said)

    def listen(self):
        """Uses speech_recognition library to listen to get audio input and understand what the user is saying"""

        with self.mic as source:
            print("listening")
            audio = self.r.listen(source, timeout=7, phrase_time_limit=10)

        return self.r.recognize_google(audio)

    def say(self, text):
        """Uses pyttsx3 engine text-to-speech to say 'text' argument"""

        self.speech_engine.say(text)
        self.speech_engine.runAndWait()

    def reply(self, text):
        intent = intent_classifier.predict(text)
        if intent == "weather":
            self.say(get_weather())
        elif intent == "greeting":
            self.say("Hello there!")
        else:
            self.say("See you later!")


assistant = Assistant("Assistant")  # Create an instance and name it "Assistant"


root.mainloop()
```

I tried moving the function around, changing it from a direct call to one that used a boolean variable.  Nothing worked.

Comment: You commented out the loop, maybe this is why it runs only once?

Comment: Thanks. That while loop had the program listen for a response and respond on an infinite loop.  I added the button and took away the while statement to allow the user to initiate the process and have it run once.  The idea was that after it ran, it would return the user back to the window, where they could click the button again.  The user could then close the window to close the application.  I tried putting the while loop back.  When I did, clicking the button started an infinite loop of asking and answering with no way to quit.

Comment: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/pull/226/commits/15db25bc9dfc6e65655412851a52dbf9e4fd9105